# php separate string by capitals

Tags: php, regex, string

I have for example this string: `"iCanSeeBluePeople"` and I need it to separate it into array by **capital letters** and the **first word** which starts with **lowercase** so I would recieve array like `["i","Can","See","Blue","People"]`

The strings can be like `"grandPrix2009"` => `["grand","Prix","2009"]`, `"dog"` => `["dog"]`, `"aDog"` => `["a","Dog"]` and so on

I found this code which works fine but I doesn't apply to numbers and ignores the fist lowercase letter:

```
<?
$str="MustangBlueHeadlining";

preg_match_all('/[A-Z][^A-Z]*/',$str,$results);
?>
```

Thanks for help

Comment: not sure that this can be done with a single regex. you will most likely have to walk the string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the regex `/[a-z]+|[A-Z]+[a-z]*|[0-9]+/`.

```
<?
    $str="thisIsATestVariableNumber000";
    preg_match_all('/[a-z]+|[A-Z]+[a-z]*|[0-9]+/',$str,$results);
    print_r($results);
?>
```

[Result](http://ideone.com/CyswZ):

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
    (
        [0] => this
        [1] => Is
        [2] => ATest
        [3] => Variable
        [4] => Number
        [5] => 000
    )

)
```

---

Use `/[a-z]+|[A-Z][a-z]*|[0-9]+/` if you want `ATest` to be separated into `A` and `Test`.

```
<?
    $str="thisIsATestVariableNumber000";
    preg_match_all('/[a-z]+|[A-Z][a-z]*|[0-9]+/',$str,$results);
    print_r($results);
?>
```

[Result](http://ideone.com/YTCaC):

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
    (
        [0] => this
        [1] => Is
        [2] => A
        [3] => Test
        [4] => Variable
        [5] => Number
        [6] => 000
    )

)
```

Comment: I forgot to mention this string: "letItBeANiceCar". There's AN which your regex doesn't include

Comment: @simPod - What's the result that you want to get for: "letItBeANiceCar"? It is either [this](http://ideone.com/x9pWu) (first regex) or [this](http://ideone.com/XYena) (second regex).

Comment: The second one. Thanks a lot for your exhausting reply. It works like charm